# ExpressJS+NodeJS server won't serve CSS files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, get

I'm trying to host my own web server, so i redirected traffic from the domain to my computer. Traffic is successfully reaching my computer and the website is being displayed except ExpressJS is not serving the only CSS file so the content on my website is all over the place because its not being styled.

The failed GET of the CSS file is seen in the console:

```
resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT xxx.xx.xx.xxx/styles.176e4d821cc3a21887b2.bundle.css Failed to load
```

Looking further into the error we see it is the only file that failed, even though all the files are in the same physical directory as you see on the next image: [image]

I'm using Angular and this is my dist deployment folder and you can see the CSS file is in the same locations as the JS files but only the CSS file fails to be GET'd: [image]

In Express i have the following which seems to serve the JS and HTML files but not the CSS file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

Also, everything works perfect on localhost, its only on traffic redirected from my .com website that the site fails to GET the css file.

Comment: Are you running this on port 80?

Comment: Yes, it connects fine and serves every client file needed, except the CSS file

Comment: Have you checked the ownership of the CSS file?

Comment: I saw and its the same ownership as the rest of the files. I did more debugging and saw that theres ~20% chance that my website sa****.ca manages to retrieve the css files and actually load the website perfect. This defies logic im very confused. I found when i forward my domain to my IP WITHOUT masking, the website retrieves all the files without issue, but when i forward domain WITH masking, the website has these routing/network/HTTP GET request problems retrieving files. So i think domain masking is somehow the issue. Also im not using IIS, simply running node via GIT Bash on Windows